# accidentally use lvm during installation of 13.10

Tags: lvm

I have 2 partitions, one is for window and the other one is for Ubuntu.
However I had a 12.04 version of Ubuntu , and I want to upgrade to 13.10. 
During installation process I choose replace 12.04 with 13.10 then there is a lvm option and I accidentally clicked on that , I thought Ubuntu would warn me if any data is wiped.
Do you have a way to recovery my window partition back?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly the same thing. I recovered my data by installing and using TestDisk. Instructions on how to use it are here:
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

But there really should be a warning next to the LVM checkbox at install!